# Eclipse plugin drag and drop

Tags: eclipse, plugins, drag-and-drop

I have developed an eclipse view where some items are displayed in a tree. I want to enable dragging concepts from the tree, and drop them into the text area of a .java file that is opened for editing.

Does anyone have any sample code, or any link to help me?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse [drag and drop tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDragAndDrop/article.html) by Lars Vogel might be of some help. IBM itself also created a [tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Workbench-DND/drag_drop.html), but I would be careful with that one, given it is 9 years old.